# No back light on my Acer Aspire 5734z

Tags: 12.04, drivers, laptop, brightness, backlight

I installed Ubuntu (12.04) on my Acer Aspire 5734z and the back light stopped working. I have tried the fix by editing the grub file posted on here a couple of days ago but that hasn't fixed it. I have also looked for hardware drivers but that didn't get me anywhere. When I hook up an external monitor it works fine but I have been unsuccessful getting the laptop display to light up.

Thanks

edit removed link

I found a fix here " http://crunchbanglinux.org/forums/post/66562/#p66562 " if anyone has a better fix than the one in that post, let me know.

Comment: try executing `sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=00`. Let us know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

web-e's `setpci` command (from the comment) helps me:

```
setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=00
```

Now the backlight changes.

Answer (score 0):

Nope  didn't work, once you reboot, it's back to step one. I spent almost 2 hours looking for a damn solution and thank the lord almighty I found it! :D I also have an acer aspire 5734z. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1900024

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.